# How do I speed up a SQL UPDATE that also contains a JOIN on 25 million rows

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

the query i'd like to speed up (or replace with another process):

```
UPDATE en_pages, keywords
SET en_pages.keyword = keywords.keyword
WHERE en_pages.keyword_id = keywords.id
```

table en_pages has the proper structure but only has non-unique page_ids and keyword_ids in it.  i'm trying to add the actual keywords(strings) to this table where they match keyword_ids.  there are 25 million rows in table en_pages that need updating.

i'm adding the keywords so that this one table can be queried in real time and return keywords (the join is obviously too slow for "real time").

we apply this query (and some others) to sub units of our larger dataset.  we do this frequently to create custom interfaces for specific sub units of our data for different user groups (sorry if that's confusing).

this all works fine if you give it an hour to run, but i'm trying to speed it up.

is there a better way to do this that would be faster using php and/or mysql?

Comment: Why would you update the whole table that frequently?

Comment: What's the table engine, what's your hardware, what's your MySQL instance config etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't think you can speed up the process.

You can still add brutal power to your database by cluserting new servers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong or missunderstood the question but...
Couldn't you use **TRIGGERS** ?
Like... when a new INSERT is detected on "en_pages", doing a UPDATE after on that same row?
(I don't know how frequent INSERTS are in that table)
This is just an idea.
How often does "en_pages.keyword" and "en_pages.keyword_id" changes after being inserted ?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about mySQL but usually this sort of thing runs faster in SQL Server if you process a limited number of batches of records (say a 1000) at a time in a loop.

You might also consider a where clause (I don't know what mySQL uses for "not equal to" so I used the SQL Server verion):

```
WHERE en_pages.keyword <> keywords.keyword
```

That way you are only updating records that have a difference in the field you are updating not all of the them.